# Group records from two dates in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime, grouping

Given the following table structure below, I have the following problem:

```
                                    Table "public.search"

 Column           |            Type             |                       Modifiers                       
------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id               | bigint                      | not null default nextval('search_id_seq'::regclass)
 date             | timestamp without time zone | 
 datesolicitation | timestamp without time zone | 
 reason           | character varying(255)      | 
 notice           | real                        | not null
 situation        | character(1)                | not null
 urgent           | boolean                     | not null
 expiring         | timestamp without time zone | 
 bond             | character(1)                | not null
 company_id       | bigint                      | 
 vehicle_id       | bigint                      | 
 driver_id        | bigint                      | 
 locality_id      | bigint                      | 
 set_id           | bigint                      | 
 composition_id   | bigint                      | 
 responsible_id   | bigint                      | 
 fleet            | character varying(255)      |
```

Every day I run a query that returns all the records to expire in the next five days based on the table expiring column:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(id) AS total
FROM search 
WHERE
  bond IN ('F', 'A', 'G', 'J')
  AND expiring - interval '5 day' between '2017-09-25 12:00:00' and '2017-09-26 12:00:00';

 total 
-------
   504
(1 row)
```

The problem occurs when the query in question is executed for another day or when we have more than one "base" date for return.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS total
  TO_CHAR(expiring, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
FROM search 
WHERE
  vinculo IN ('F', 'A', 'G', 'J')
  AND expiring - interval '5 day' between '2017-09-25 12:00:00' AND '2017-09-28 12:00:00'
GROUP BY expiring;

 total |  to_char   
-------+------------
     1 | 30/09/2017
     1 | 30/09/2017
     1 | 30/09/2017
     1 | 30/09/2017
     1 | 30/09/2017
     1 | 30/09/2017
```

Since the consultation period is from 12:00:00 a day until 12:00:00 on another or that is on September 25 as presented in the query will also be considered all records from September 26 to 12 : 00: 00.
On September 26 will also be considered the records of September 27 successively.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Something like `group by date_trunc('day', expiring - '11:59:59'::time)`?

Answer (score 1):

what about instead you do:

```
WHERE expiring BETWEEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
                   AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '5 days'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(expiring, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```